# MySQL suddenly not working on Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, mysql

I installed PHP and MySQL on our windows 2003 server about 3 months ago. Everything has been working wonderfully, but for some reason when I came into work this morning, the service had stopped working. I proceeded to start the service up again, shortly there after the service stopped again. In the Event Log for the server I have the following errors:

Application Event: Source: Application Error, Category 100, Event ID: 1000, Description: Faulting application mysqld.exe, version 0.0.0.0, faulting module mysqld.exe, version 0.0.0.0, fault address 0x002aafd7.

System Event: Source: Service Control Manager, Description: The MySQL service terminated unexpectedly. It has done this 2 time(s).

I figured something was just buggy, so I rebooted the server, same problem. As far as I know, nothing was changed on the server over the weekend.

When I launched MySQL Administrator that installed with it, And click on the Server logs, their is no information, and most boxes are grayed out.

If somebody could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: maybe add some output from mysql logs?

what happens when you try to start mysqld from command line [ not as a service ] ?

Comment: Sorry, the error code I copied to:

http://pastebin.com/m103c467a

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Was the 2k3 box patched over the weekend?

Comment: Not that I'm aware off.  I'm in contact with our outside server vendor and that was the first thing I asked them, and they said nobody from their end accessed the server over the weekend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of your logs, you're hitting database errors.  Ideally this would not cause the service to crash.  I would look into the mysqlcheck and the associated table repair utilities to see about repairing any database errors you might have to see if that clears things up.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqlcheck.html

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I just ran mysqlcheck --all-databases

The output was:
echo.addtypes
echo.boilerplates
mysqlcheck: Got error: 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query when executing 'CHECK TABLE ... '

It appears the the MySQL service crapped out during the middle of the check.  Ugh.

Answer (score 0):

if you have backups - take lazy way and just restore from them. remove all table files [ or even all database dirs except mysql ] from data directory, then restore from backup.
possibly you'll have to remove ib_logfileX and ibdataX files as well.

otherwise - i'm afraid you are about to gain experience in [recovering innodb databases](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/11/26/data-recovery-toolkit-for-innodb-version-01-released/)...  [ i assume you use this storage somewhere, at least log suggests crash around it ].

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like database corruption to me. Try a fresh install. Then restore databases one at a time till it goes crunch. Then at least you know which one is the problem. Get rid of that one and restore the rest. That just leaves you with the problem of how to repair the troublesome one. It if was mine I'd go back to an earlier backup. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

Open the MySQL administrator UI and untick `Data directory` in the `Startup Variables` section.

Comment: You could look at improving your question by going into a little more detail.